# Fetch file with ajax — CORS issue & set cache?

Tags: php, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to get a json file with fetch from another server:

```
fetch('https://site.test/data.json',
    {
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

If I fetch directly I receive the CORS issue.

If I fetch via PHP I don't have the CORS issue, but I don't get the file itself so it can't be cached.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo file_get_contents("data.json");
```

Is it possible to somehow return the file itself and ideally set cache header in php?

Comment: Well you could use PHP + a cache system, to cache a copy of it, perhaps.

Comment: You could also try to set an "Expires"-header in PHP. Or put a php script on your side that fetches the file and stores it under your domain periodically.

Comment: If you have access to the remote server, you can make sure to add the CORS headers to the request of the actual file, of course.

Comment: @volkerschulz I have access to remote server, but I'm not sure how to add headers to actual file

Comment: Depends on which server you are using. If it is an Apache web server, you could use the Header directive inside a .htaccess file (for the whole host or particular files)

Comment: Using regular Apache. So there is no way to return the file via php somehow?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "return the file". Any requests just returns data. ;)

Comment: Yeah per my understanding data is more complex to cache and file can be cached easier. Also I believe cache can be reset on file easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an apache host you can simply put an .htaccess file inside the same directory (or any parent directory) your JSON file is in and add the following:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

This will set the appropriate header for all requests of .json files. You can also specify allowed methods and headers as needed.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks — would it also possible to set cache via htaccess?

Comment: Sure, you can add / set additional headers the very same way. For caching it would be something like: Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200, must-revalidate"

Comment: Thanks so much! Would it be reset if the file is changed or it will require some additional coding?

Comment: The Cache-Control directive mentioned above instructs the client to use this exact copy for the next 7200 seconds (2 hours) and not bother the server with further requests (which is the whole purpose of caching). So the client has no way to know whether the file on the sever has changed. After 2 hours however, the client must check once again (by requesting the headers or the whole file).

Comment: I see — thanks — so the only way to clear cache on file change would be in php?

Comment: No, there's simply no way to clear the client's cache from the server. If you want the client to always use the latest version of the file, you need to disable caching. The server can still return "Not Modified" on further requests, if the file hasn't changed since the last request from that client.